# How to create collapsible onclick of div in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

How to make collapsible onclick of `<div className="content-header">` in Reactjs

As I am beginner in Reactjs how can I create a function that will handle onclick div section to make that collapsible

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="content">
        <div className="content-header">
          <p>STEM</p>
        </div>
        <div className="content-body">
          I am a STEM
          <br></br>
          I am STEM
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="content">

        <div className="content-header">

          <p>STEM</p>

        </div>

        <div className="content-body">

          I am a STEM

          <br></br>

          I am STEM

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

This is how it look like

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isShowBody, setIsSHowBody] = React.useState(false);

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setIsSHowBody(isShowBody => !isShowBody);
  }

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="content">
        <div className="content-header" onClick={onClickHandler}>
          <p>STEM</p>
        </div>
        { isShowBody && <div className="content-body">
          I am a STEM
          <br></br>
          I am STEM
        </div>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @dellink Its working fine but have one problem suppose I have multiple ```<div className="content">``` then on a click of a single ```<div className="content-header">``` all are collapses and expanded. I just update question similarly I have 50 these kind of div.

Comment: create component for `<div className="content">` and use it everywhere

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
import {React,useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [open,setOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {setOpen(!open)}

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="content">
        <div className="content-header" onClick={toggle}>
          <p>STEM</p>
        </div>
        {open?

        <div className="content-body">
          I am a STEM
          <br></br>
          I am STEM
        </div>:null
       }
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

if you have multiple, you have to use `open` array :

```
import {React,useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [open,setOpen] = useState([false,false,false]);

  const toggle = (i) => {let copyOpen = open; open[i] = !open[i] ;setOpen(copyOpen)}

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="content">
        <div className="content-header" onClick={()=>toggle(0)}>
          <p>STEM</p>
        </div>
        {open[0]?

        <div className="content-body">
          I am a STEM
          <br></br>
          I am STEM
        </div>:null
       }
        <div className="content-header" onClick={()=>toggle(1)}>
          <p>STEM</p>
        </div>
        {open[1]?

        <div className="content-body">
          I am a STEM
          <br></br>
          I am STEM
        </div>:null
       }
        <div className="content-header" onClick={()=>toggle(2)}>
          <p>STEM</p>
        </div>
        {open[2]?

        <div className="content-body">
          I am a STEM
          <br></br>
          I am STEM
        </div>:null
       }
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nilanka Manoj  one problem suppose I have multiple ```<div className="content">``` then on a click of a single ```<div className="content-header">``` all are collapses and expanded. I just update question similarly I have 50 these kind of div.

Comment: Hi @Nilanka Manoj I don't think this is right approach because if I use map or forEach function for creating the div section and  suppose map functioncreates 50Div section then I will write 50 timess false inside of useState.

Comment: This is the basic idea, you can initialize array with array size, then map the content while gving the index to the toggle function]